# EF Core: How can I access a property in a derived class inside another related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to access properties from derived class in TPH.

Base class

```
public abstract class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public AuthorType AuthorType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}
```

Derived class

```
public class Organization : Author
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Configurations

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
                .HasDiscriminator(a => a.AuthorType)
                .HasValue<Person>(AuthorType.Person)
                .HasValue<Organization>(AuthorType.Organization);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Posts);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Author)
                .WithMany(p => p.Posts);
}
```

I want to access property Name in Posts of Organization:

```
Author author = new Organization { Name = "CA", OrganizationType = OrganizationType.NonProfit};

Post post = new Post { Subject = "News", Author = author, Tag = PostTag.SualatUpdate};

context.Add(author);
context.Add(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable like this: `Author author = new Organization` therefore your variable will be of type `Author` - which does not have a property of 'Name'.

You may need to re-look at how you are doing things here.  You may simply declare the variable as `Organisation author = new Organisation`.  But it's hard to know more without guessing.

[OT: My 2 cents worth - don't over use inheritance.  it's ok to start out with some repeated code then later you can see the patterns emerge and re-factor.]

Comment: declaring the variable as  `Organization` doesn't allow me to retreive Posts (`context.Posts`) and get property `Name` from `Organization` because `Post` class only have `Author` as property (navigation) not `Name`. So you don't suggest me to use inheritance here in my model domain.

Comment: huh? if you inherit from another class you get all their public properties for free.  so you should be able to see Posts for sure!

Comment: Ok @John thank you for refresh me about inheritance. But even so I'm not clear on **How can I access** `Name` **property from** `context.Posts`? I want an output like this: 

**List of posts: 
Author Name | Subject**
Some Name | Some subject

But need to consider that Author Name must be get by `Name` property from class `Organization` that inherits from `Author`. And `Author` doesn't have `Name` property

Comment: If i'm reading this right you actually want a navigation property on your `Post` class to it parent `Author`

Comment: so you would end up with code like `post.ParentAuthor.Name` for example

Comment: No. I think my question is not complete that make some noise. A added the post class that I left in the original ask. I can't code `post.ParentAuthor.Name` because `Author` that is parent/base class doesn't have `Name` property. `Name` property is inside `Organization` that inherits from `Author`.

Comment: my bad - ok so you have a `ParentOrganization` property on `Post` class...

Comment: Yes. Parent on Post. And post has navigation property Author that is Parent.

Comment: you just said "And post has navigation property Author that is Parent" - this where it's going wrong...

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: i think the navigation property (eg `Parent` ) on `Post` class needs to be of type `Organization`

Comment: Ok. This resolves the problem to get `Name` property from `Organization`. But what about to get `FirstName` property from `Person` that also inherits from same parent (Author) that`Organization` inherits. I have two entities of the same level on hierarchy that inherits from Author (`Person` and `Organization`). Following your approach, I have to insert `Person` as another navigation property on Post also. But in my model, a `Post` belongs to **only one** `Author` that is an `Organization` or `Person`, not both of them.

Comment: set the iheritance aside for a moment and code it up even if you have to do a bit of repeating.  once it's all working then if you must and think it worthwhile use inheritance.  good luck!

Comment: Ok. I'll do it. Thanks!